# Do wires connecting to an external electrical panel require outdoor rating?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I am working on wiring an extension panel mounted on the outside wall of the house. The wires travel in the crawlspace in a conduit and the conduit is connected to the panel.

Do I need to use outdoor/waterproof wires to connect to an outdoor panel?

What type of wire is recommended?

Comment: I think if the wires travel on the outside wall any length in conduit or not, they need to be rated for wet conditions.  If just going right though the wall into the panel, they do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A conduit which is outside, is outside.  NM wire is not allowed in an outside conduit.

NM cable does not like getting wet. The paper wadding will wick up water, where it will rot the wire insulation.  We know this because it'll start tripping GFCIs.  Virtually every inspector will bless NM cable coming *straight through the wall* into an outdoor mounted panel, because the alternative is ridiculous.  But a transit along an outside wall will require a different type of wire or cable.

Now, some people get the "bright idea" to run a huge conduit outdoors along the outside wall to the panel, and their plan is to throw *a whole bunch* of Romex cables in there.  Nope.  Can't do it.  As soon as you put 2 cables in there, 310.15(B)(3)(a) applies and forces you to **derate** the ampacity of the cable. And that stops you at 3 cables, or 4 if they are all 15-20A.

The better answer, really, is an indoor panel, if an appropriate indoor location can be secured.  This is better anyway. Most circuits these days need AFCI or GFCI breakers, and those don't last nearly as long outdoors.

Comment: Thank you @Harper - Reinstate Monica. What is the logic behind 310.15(B)(3)(a) and derating the ampacity?

Comment: @Max because wires make heat. Too many wires in close proximity cannot cool, [and this happens](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/192923/why-is-it-dangerous-use-a-coiled-extension-cord). In conduit, your thermal limitation is the shell of the conduit.  Mind you the conduit may also be soaking up solar gain.

Answer (score 2):

*Most* individual wires for use in residential wiring in conduit are actually rated *both* THHN (dry only) and THWN (wet). So most of the time this is a non-issue. The exception is with *cables*, as standard NM cable (a.k.a., Romex) is only rated for dry locations.